# Flutter landing page to navigate user depends on a state

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, navigation

How can I navigate the user to the relevant screen? For example, If the user signed in, then the user must go homepage, but the user did not sign in, so the user must go login page. When I try to use navigator, then it gives this error:

**FlutterError (setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey#3ba8a]
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
BlocBuilder<AuthCubit, AuthState>)**

Also, I used auto route and auto route generator, but it gives an error is: **The getter 'RouteInformationReportingType' isn't defined for the class 'AutoRouteInformationProvider'. package:auto_route/…/provider/auto_route_information_provider.dart:32**

Can you help me?

[image: error img]

codes:

```
class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LandingPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocBuilder<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state.isUserSignedIn) {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomePage()),
            );
          } else {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SignInPage()),
            );
          }
          return Container();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Btw, I do not want to return directly the page. I want to navigate the user.

Comment: just wrap that push method between this tags WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated flutter sdk to 2.8 and some syntax changes. That's it

Comment: also, there is a package whose name is flow_builder. It solved my problem

Answer (score -1):

you have to change code like this, this will reder after all widget has been initialized, so it will navigate after initializing of all widgets.

```
if (state.isUserSignedIn) {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomePage()),
            );
          } else {
            WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
               Navigator.push(
                 context,
                 MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SignInPage()),
               );
             });
          }
```

Comment: I changed but it still gives the same error.

Comment: actually the same i have tried my side an it works :(

Comment: yes, but it is not a solution for me. I just try to navigate users according to state.

Comment: bro then you have to put loader or something to check and wait while the checking in progress so you can check if state has some values then and then perform the if else condition.. because every time the state is null that's why it perfom else part

Comment: for more you can follow this tutorial it might help.. https://medium.com/swlh/create-a-splash-screen-with-bloc-in-flutter-c495ef22b1be